# WooCommerce Shopping Cart Not Showing Products at Check Out

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I am working with a WooCommerce site that is experiencing a strange issue. The customers can add the products to the cart but when they go to the cart to check out, the cart is empty. It doesn’t happen all the time but it seems to happen when they leave the cart and went back to the shop to add more items.

I have updated all the plugins, themes, PHP versions and tested turning on/off the plugins to see if it's interfering with the theme, but nothing has worked.

I am running WooCommerce v.3.6.5, running WordPress 5.2.2, with PHP version 7.0.33. My host is GoDaddy.

Comment: Do share the code where you are facing the issue.

Comment: This can be related to your theme, a plugin or your hosting server and settings… Nobody can guess where is your problem coming from.